# Multi-word search queries using the Freebase search service

Tags: search, google-api, freebase

I am trying to search for topics using the search service api and I want to use multiple words to narrow the search results. For instance, search for "Tide" returns many results reflecting the different meanings of the word and the different topics in Freebase. However, since I'm particularly interested in topics that have to do with Tide as a detergent and brand, I want to find results by adding informative words to the search string. For example, by searching for "Tide+detergent+household+soap" I hoped to boost the scores of results in which  Tide is associated with detergent etc.  I had expected that such searches would be based on some sort of vector space scoring as in Lucene so that not all terms have to be present in an indexed topic document. However, since the query fails to return a result, it appears as though all words have to be to be present.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=tide+detergent+household+soap&indent=true
```

returns the result:

```
{
 "status": "200 OK",
 "result": [
  ],
 "cost": 6,
 "hits": 0
}
```

Is there a way to use filters to address this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Freebase keyword search API does accept multiple keywords but it's mostly indexed off of the names of topic, not off of keywords found in documents related to the topics (like Google search). There are currently no topics in Freebase called "tide detergent household soap".

Your intuition is right about using a filter to get the results that you want. Filtering by type /business/brand should give you what you're looking for:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=tide&filter=(all+type%3A%2Fbusiness%2Fbrand)&indent=true

Comment: Hi Shawn:
Thanks much for your answer. I am still puzzled about the way the documents are indexed. The old search service [link](http://www.freebase.com/docs/web_services/search) appears to index terms from different fields (anchors, name, alias, wikipedia etc.) and use these to compute a Lucene score. Has that changed in the new version? Also, while there are no topics called "tide detergent household soap", shouldn't such a search find topics that match the words in the search query most closely? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The new search index still includes all those signal but I believe that it has a threshold for which results it shows. Perhaps your keywords didn't have a strong enough score to show any results.